# RegEx: replace multiple values in text

Tags: python-3.x, regex, substitution, python-re, regexp-replace

I have a text file where each line contains specific values. They change often. I’d like to replace two values on a single line in one go without rewriting the entire line.

```
Current regex pattern:
(\(Psig\)- )(\d+\.\d+)

Regex to do one value at a time:
^(.*?(.*?\(Psig\)- ){1})(\d+\.\d+)

Using \1 backreference to change values
```

Line from file:

```
RPM- 1400, (Psig)- 57.66, Ts- 48.11, (Psig)- 299.33
```

I currently want to change the values that follows `(Psig)-` , currently pattern both values that I need to change but when using back reference it changes both values to same thing.

In this example:

57.66-> 22.77

299.33-> 355.26

I was thinking to use re.sub() to replace these values. Is this possible to do with this method or is there another option to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are only two matches in the line, would you please try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

s = 'RPM- 1400, (Psig)- 57.66, Ts- 48.11, (Psig)- 299.33'
newval = ['22.77', '355.26']            # array of new values
val_iter = iter(newval)                 # iterator to return each new value

s = re.sub(r'(?<=\(Psig\)- )[\d.]+', lambda x: next(val_iter), s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
RPM- 1400, (Psig)- 22.77, Ts- 48.11, (Psig)- 355.26
```

The regex `(?<=\(Psig\)- )[\d.]+` matches a decimal value preceded by the string `(Psig)-` . Each time the regex matches, the value is replaced with the output of the iterator.

Comment: This works for this example; which is good. 

However what if you have a 3rd (Psig) in the string but only only have two indexes in newValue; where it only changes just the first two values and leaves 3rd alone

Comment: I solved this example using re.finditer() and loop through matches while zipping through a list of newValues like yours. But your example is cleaner

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
As you point out, it causes an error when there are three or more matches.
I should have commented I'm assuming there are only two matches.
I suppose the point is to pick an appropriate method depending on the
condition or nature of the inputs. In that sense, using a loop will be
a good choice in terms of robustness.